# Why button changes size when color changed?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am writing a simple tic tac toe application that has 3 by 3 array of buttons, when someone wins it changes colors, however when colors change it becomes of bigger size and you cannot see individual buttons? so my question is how do i make them change color but stay the same size? picture is instead of thousand words attached. the below code is non contiguous, first i initialize button to default, then when we have a winner color of winning buttons will change and then on game reset I return buttons to the default state; please tell me how to make button color red without it going out of button boundaries or if there is a better way to implement the entire thing.

```
button00.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
button00.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
button00.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
```

**Layout XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button00"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button01"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button01"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button02"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button00"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button00"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button00"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button10"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button00"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button00"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button11"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button10"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button10"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button02"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button12"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button11"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button11"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button02"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button20"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Button10"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button21"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button20"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button20"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Button12"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button22"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Button21"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Button21"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button12"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/testButton"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button20"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Button20"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />
     <!-- 
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resetButton"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/testButton"
            android:layout_below="@+id/testButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" /> -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

> [image: initial state]
>
> [image: color change state]

Comment: can you post layout xml?

Comment: posted, not sure why u need it

Comment: why you are setting background resource ? remove this line : button00.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default); and then try again.

Comment: just do this : button00.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

Comment: wqrahd - this is something i do, because if i don't do this then when starting new game buttons will remain red

Comment: You'll have to make an image that is "a Button with red background" to get the result you want.

Comment: you mean there is no way to do it without creating images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Button` background color by `setBackgroundResource()` in the following line...

```
button00.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Use `setColorFilter()` as the below line...

```
button00.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

So, your updated code will be...

```
button00.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
button00.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't try to change the Background resource You only change the color I think you have done  the mistake in changing the Background resource Try it like that without changing the Resource... And execute it I hope it will Work Properly..

Answer (score 0):

```
> button00.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
> button00.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
> button00.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
```

don't use this 
use
button00.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_default);