# How to prevent buttons from getting bigger when pressed

Tags: android, button

I am practicing changing button colors when another button is pressed but every time I press the button to change the color the buttons enlarge as well. Is there something I need to define in the XML to keep the button size constant when pressed? I also was wondering if relative vs linear layout would make a difference in this?

CODE:

```
private Button back;
private Button front;
private Button b1;
private Button b2;

Button[] buttons = new Button[4];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    front = (Button) findViewById(R.id.front);
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);

    buttons[0] = front;
    buttons[1] = back;
    buttons[2] = b1;
    buttons[3] = b2;

    front.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
                if (buttons[i] == buttons[2]) {
                    buttons[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                else
                    buttons[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

XML:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/front"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:text="Front"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/front"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="b1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/front"
    android:layout_below="@+id/front" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/b2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="b2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b1"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default button background drawable has some kind of margins. These Buttons margins have a transparent color when you change the color of the button then the transparent color is changed into a new color you assigned then the button size will be enlarged.  [Use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162873/why-button-changes-size-when-color-changed) to change color of button.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to set a `backgroundTint` instead of a backgroundColor. A `backgroundColor` gives a background color to the view, not the button. A backgroundTint however, gives the button itself a color.
When you set it you have to user the `BackgroundTintList`, but you can just give a color by using `ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.MY_COLOR)`.

So your code should be

```
        if (buttons[i] == buttons[2]) {
            buttons[i].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
        }
        else
            buttons[i].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GRAY));
```

Hope this helps you!